# How to find out if a notification is scheduled?

Tags: flutter, notifications

Using `flutter_local_notifications` I create a scheduled notification like this:

```
final tz.TZDateTime nextInstance = calcNextInstanceOfDayOfWeekAndTime(dayOfWeek, hour, minute);
await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
  notificationId,
  title,
  body,
  nextInstance,
  matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime,
  uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
  // ... payload and other details
);
```

Some days later I want to check if `notificationId` is scheduled or not.

Or more generally speaking: I wonder how to get a list of the currently scheduled notifications.

If this is not possible with `flutter_local_notifications` is that possible with `awesome_notifications`? I could not find any information in the readmes of the packages regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `awesome_notifications` there is a method to list all scheduled notifications:

```
AwesomeNotifications().listScheduledNotifications()
```